# Sidewall of tire repair not leaking or deflating

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

How can i fix this? Its not fully punctured and not leaking

Comment: Not a duplicate; check title: not leaking or deflating.

Comment: You know the right answer here... buy a new tire. That thing is dangerous.

Comment: Is there any damage to the sidewall itself (past the rubber and into the cords)?

Answer (score 3):

It could probably be repaired, but the sidewall is now severely weakened. Even without leaking, it could fail at any moment. You don't want a blow-out while driving 70mph in traffic on the highway.

Replace the tire.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Answer good , upvote because even if visible damage does not reach the cords they could be weakened . As said replace - it's your safety and that of any traveling with you...

Comment: There is no "repairing" that.  With what,  decoupage glue??  I didn't downvote, but don't put those kinds of ideas in the OP's head. You won't find anybody reputable anyway that would assume the risk. Your thrust is correct, replace the tire.  While I might not, that's my personal responsibility and NOBODY here (including me) is capable of fully judging the damage, driving style, and loading on that tire.  Repalce the tire.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the sidewall cords are not damaged, the rubber that supported them is now useless.

**Cut the hooks of a woman's bra (but don't damage any underwire or material!) and ask her if she's still willing to wear it...**

Replace the tire.

No reputable tire place or mechanic should even **attempt** to repair that, unless they have the orginal mold and could re-vulcanize the tire *(Live long and prosper...)*

By the same token, NOBODY here, mechanic or otherwise, should even suggest it's okay to continue driving on it, I don't care if their Magic 8 Ball has a chrome stand and LED mood lighting.  Just because *I* might jump off a bridge like a lemming is not a sound judgement on the longetivity of that sidewall carcass.

That looks like a really nice rim (love the centercap) for that 325, do you want to risk (at minimum) a blowout and buying a new tire AND rim??

Replace the tire.

On the other hand, if you want, you could replace the tire...

*(Just because I have no friends doesn't make me wrong.)*